# How to find the datasize of Oracle db?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to find the  datasize of Oracle db by using following query

```
select round((sum(bytes)/1048576/1024),2) from v$datafile;
```

But facing **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist** error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you the DBA?  Based on the error, it appears that your DBA hasn't given you access to the `v$datafile` view.  Most likely you'd want to ask for the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege or the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role.  Or the DBA could grant you just access to that particular view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur suggestion . Let me check the privileges with my DBA den.